# R: Remove Duplicate Values in Column A When Column B Matches

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with three columns: Group, Amplitude Origin.   I want to remove duplicate values in Amplitude within the same Group.  I could not find a way to subset by group with `unique()` and couldn’t think of a way to apply `case_when()`.  I have many group values, so while I can imagine how to hard code and if statement for each group, I imagine there is a better way to do this.

Thanks!

```
df <- data.frame(
  Group = c(rep("A",4), rep("B",3), rep("A",2), rep("B",4)),
  Amplitude = c(2,3,5,7,2,4,6,2,4,2,4,6,9),
  Origin = c(rep("Drug", 7), rep("Placebo", 6))
  )

desired_df <- data.frame(
  Group = c(rep("A",5), rep("B",4)),
  Amplitude = c(2,3,4,5,7,2,4,6,9)
  )

>df
| Group | Amplitude | Origin  |
|-------|-----------|---------|
| A     | 2         | Drug    |
| A     | 3         | Drug    |
| A     | 5         | Drug    |
| A     | 7         | Drug    |
| B     | 2         | Drug    |
| B     | 4         | Drug    |
| B     | 6         | Drug    |
| A     | 2         | Placebo |
| A     | 4         | Placebo |
| B     | 2         | Placebo |
| B     | 4         | Placebo |
| B     | 6         | Placebo |
| B     | 9         | Placebo |


>desired_df
| Group | Amplitude |
|-------|-----------|
| A     | 2         |
| A     | 3         |
| A     | 4         |
| A     | 5         |
| A     | 7         |
| B     | 2         |
| B     | 4         |
| B     | 6         |
| B     | 9         |
…
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## base R

`duplicated` is a good function here,

```r
df[!duplicated(df[, c("Group", "Amplitude")]),]
#    Group Amplitude  Origin
# 1      A         2    Drug
# 2      A         3    Drug
# 3      A         5    Drug
# 4      A         7    Drug
# 5      B         2    Drug
# 6      B         4    Drug
# 7      B         6    Drug
# 9      A         4 Placebo
# 13     B         9 Placebo
```

You can remove `Origin` if you don't need it anymore.

Alternatively, you can use `unique` on an already-subsetted frame.

```r
unique(df[,c("Group", "Amplitude")])
```

## dplyr

```r
dplyr::distinct(df, Group, Amplitude)
#   Group Amplitude
# 1     A         2
# 2     A         3
# 3     A         5
# 4     A         7
# 5     B         2
# 6     B         4
# 7     B         6
# 8     A         4
# 9     B         9
```

(You can add `.keep_all=TRUE` if you want to preserve the `Origin` column as I did in the base-R example.)

Comment: I didn't see a  case use in the help of `dplyr::distinct` where multiple columns could be entered.  Is `dplyr::distinct(df, Group, Amplitude)` the same as df %>% group_by(Group) %>% distinct(Amplitude)` ?

Comment: The two expressions should be equivalent. From [`?distinct`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/distinct.html), the `...` argument is described as *"Optional variables to use when determining uniqueness"*, which means it can be zero or more variables (using dplyr's non-standard evaluation).

Answer (score 1):

I guess `unique` should work like below

```
> unique(df[with(df, order(Group, Amplitude)), -3])
   Group Amplitude
1      A         2
2      A         3
9      A         4
3      A         5
4      A         7
5      B         2
6      B         4
7      B         6
13     B         9
```

or a bit silly way by `stack` + `unstack`

```
> rev(stack(lapply(unstack(df[-3], Amplitude ~ Group), unique)))
  ind values
1   A      2
2   A      3
3   A      5
4   A      7
5   A      4
6   B      2
7   B      4
8   B      6
9   B      9
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also subset by passing combined columns created by `cbind()` to `duplicated` function:

```
subset(df, !duplicated(cbind(Group, Amplitude)))


   Group Amplitude  Origin
1      A         2    Drug
2      A         3    Drug
3      A         5    Drug
4      A         7    Drug
5      B         2    Drug
6      B         4    Drug
7      B         6    Drug
9      A         4 Placebo
13     B         9 Placebo
```